# How to properly fork an app in Django Oscar 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am attempting to make a minor modification to the mixin.py file in the checkout app (specifically, attempting to comment out the line within `OrderPlacementMixin` that automatically sends an email after a successful order as described in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112273/disable-order-email-in-django-oscar)).  However, I can't seem to get oscar to recognize my fork.  I have already followed the steps as enumerated [here](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/topics/customisation.html#fork-oscar-app), with no luck.

Here are the steps I've done

1) Create a `custom_apps` directory in the project root, and an empty `__init__.py` file inside it

2) Run `manage.py oscar_fork_app checkout custom_apps` - this command generates the `checkout` directory as well as multiple files. Here's the terminal output. I've also attached a photo of the directory structure

```sh
(venv) work@pc:~/MyProjects/oscar2_project/frobshop$ ./manage.py oscar_fork_app checkout custom_apps
Creating package custom_apps/checkout
Creating app config
Creating models.py
Replace the entry 'oscar.apps.checkout.apps.CheckoutConfig' with 'custom_apps.checkout.apps.CheckoutConfig' in INSTALLED_APPS
```

[image]

3) I commented out `'oscar.apps.checkout'` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` in my `settings.py`, and I inserted `'custom_apps.checkout'` at the end of the INSTALLED_APPS` list

4) I run `python manage.py runserver`, to which I get the exception `oscar.core.exceptions.AppNotFoundError: Couldn't find an Oscar app to import checkout.calculators from`. At this point, I haven't even tried to modify any code yet, however, my fork already refuses to run.

I would appreciate it if anyone can point out any steps I'm missing.  I understand that its possible to copy all the contents of oscar.apps.checkout, however I would like to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oscar 2.0 app configs are extended [Django apps configs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/).

It looks like your forked app module does not have a `default_app_config` specified, so you should either [add one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications), or in `INSTALLED_APPS` use the dotted path to its app config class: `custom_apps.checkout.apps.CheckoutConfig` instead of `custom_apps.checkout`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  Using `custom_apps.checkout.apps.CheckoutConfig` instead of `custom_apps.checkout` did the trick.  I tried it before, but I'm not sure why it did not work earlier. Thanks again.